# Setting up private docker registry in AWS and using it with Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, docker-registry

I have found several references on how to do this, however - I have not been able to get any of them to work. Where I get into trouble, is with trying to develop a self-signed certificate. If has recently been able to Set up private docker registry in AWS and using it with Beanstalk - please help me.

Comment: Could you be more specific and explain what you have tried and where you need help?

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of things if you are trying to deploy a private registry.

depending on the docker version, you should make a choice between `registry` and `registry 2.0`. or directly from the source? i couldn't get source to work though, and i think `registry 2.0` needs the latest `docker`. my docker api version is 1.17 and i could only get it to work with `registry`.

from my experience, there's nothing special with generating self-signed certificates, but there are some tips on adding the CA. I followed the generating self-signed certificate part of this article: [How To Set Up a Private Docker Registry on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04). I had to make the following tweaks to make it work:

#### Adding CA to a list of trusted CAs

First of all, transfer the CA `ca.pem` to all machines which will be using the registry. Next, add it to the list of trusted CAs. Depending on host's operation system, the commands are slightly different.

For `Ubuntu 14.04`:

`sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/docker-registry
sudo cp ca.pem /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/docker-registry/ca.crt
sudo update-ca-certificates`

For `CoreOs`:

`sudo cp ca.pem /etc/ssl/certs/docker_registry_ca.pem
sudo update-ca-certificates`

*Remark: `Ubuntu 14.04` only takes into account `.crt` files. `CoreOs` only takes into account `.pem` files; in addition, for `CoreOs`, the file must be in `/etc/ssl/certs/`, excluding any sub-directory*

If you are using an `nginx` container for tls, this would make the container to trust this CA as it pulls its list of trusted CAs directly from the host machine. But in addition to that, you need to ask `Docker` to trust this CA too in order to pull from and push to your future `registry` container. This is rather easy to accomplish, you just need to restart `Docker` daemon and it will reload the list of trusted CAs from the updated list.

For `Ubuntu 14.04`:

`sudo service docker restart`

For `CoreOS`:

`sudo systemctl restart docker`